# How to add sequential numbers to an empty SQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, cpanel

I'm trying to add sequential numbers, from 1 to 200M, to an empty SQL table.  The number is too large to make the list with Excel.  I'm also using Cpanel which has a low file size limit.  Any way to do this using an sql query?  (Note: other posts have given sample code for this, but they don't seem to be standard SQL queries that can be used in cpanel.)

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: I am using MySQL.

Comment: why should you create 200M rows with just the number (I assume this is an id)?

Comment: You may want to look at the methods described here: http://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2011-07-30/mysql-row-generator

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use `information_schema.columns` view.
Simple [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c62bbc/13) for 100.000 rows (only 100 thousand since I don't want to kill SQLFiddle) - it takes only a few seconds:

```
SELECT @x:=@x+1
FROM (SELECT @x:=0) xx,
information_schema.columns a,
information_schema.columns b,
information_schema.columns c,
information_schema.columns d
LIMIT 10000;
```

If your database has, say, 100 columns, then the cross join of 4 tables can give 100^4 = 100000000 potential rows, this is much more than you need.

Answer (score 0):

An iterative solution would be:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @Counter int=0
WHILE @Counter <= 2000000
    BEGIN
    INSERT tableName(columnName)
    VALUES (@Counter)
    SET @Counter=@Counter+1
    END
END
```

The drawback to this solution is that it will execute 2 million insert statements against your database.

Comment: Thank you for this.  Forgive my inexperience, but "DECLARE" doesn't seem to be a command that Cpanel recognizes.  I am entering the command you suggested in the same way one would normally enter a query.

Comment: It looks like in MySQL a DECLARE needs to be inside a BEGIN...END block according to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/declare.html

Comment: Ah!  Thanks again.